# How to add a static wait in between a step within a scenario?

Tags: karate

I used following option

```
* def sleep =
      """
      function(seconds){
        for(i = 0; i <= seconds; i++)
        {
          java.lang.Thread.sleep(1*1000);
          karate.log(i);
        }
      }
      """
* call sleep 10
```

But I want to understand if there is a better in-built way to do the same. Also want to know if static wait can be added

- In between scenario
- In between steps of a scenario
- In between feature files
- etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are doing is fine. Search for "sleep" in the readme you will find this:

```
* def sleep = function(millis){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(millis) }
* sleep(1000)
```

The answer to the second part of your question is hooks: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

I would NEVER do this, but as an example if you do `* java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)` in the `Background` - it will sleep before each `Scenario.

EDIT - please look at the `RuntimeHook` for advanced use-cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475