# Karate step hooks/ listeners like BeforeStep AfterStep is available?

Tags: karate

I would just like to know, Is it possible to have something like listeners / hooks BeforeStep AfterStep with karate? is there any way around?

Thanks in advance
Vikas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally hooks are sufficient: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

But if you are willing to write Java code, there is an `ExecutionHook` that can give you `beforeStep` and `afterStep` callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475