# Is there a way to slow down scenario execution in Karate?

Tags: karate

While developing scenarios, I would like to slow down scenario execution to better observe if steps execute the right actions. I was thinking of temporarily adding calls to `karate.stop()` after each step. Or simply debug the scenario, of course. However, I'm curious if there is an option to generally slow down scenario execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has asked for this yet :) But there is a somewhat un-documented `ExecutionHook` - so you can implement a callback that will be fired before / after each step. You can find details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475

I hope you are aware of the debugger that you get with Visual Studio Code: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1252817691963830272

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter. Maybe this would be a somewhat exotic feature. :-) I'll go with the Visual Studio Code debugger for know.

Comment: @MarkusNeifer thanks for being a good sport, I opened a feature request, feel free to add your comments, in case there was a specific use-case: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1121