# Karate DSL - karate.info is not populated when used with Scenario outline

Tags: karate

We are using Karate for testing our application. Since we need to run multiple test with different testdata we used scenario outline passing a json array in the examples. The tests are getting executed properly.

Post execution we need to publish the result to our test management tool. For that, we are trying to use the afterScenario hook as mentioned in karate documentation.

```
* configure afterScenario =
"""
function(){
  var info = karate.info;
  karate.log('after', info);
}
"""
```

After each scenario of the example executed, we see the info details printed, but the error message details, scenario name etc are not populated (title is a value from the json array passed in example section. title is printed in the karate execution report)

Karate.info printed when scenario outline is used:-

```
14:45:39.744 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time: 754, url: ##url removed###, response: ##Response removed###
14:45:39.744 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - after {
  "featureDir": "C:\\Workspace\\Karate_Demo\\target\\test-classes\\com\\test\\Karate_Demo",
  "scenarioType": "Scenario Outline",
  "featureFileName": "TestIntegration.feature",
  "errorMessage": null,
  "scenarioDescription": "",
  "scenarioName": "<title>"
}
```

Karate.info printed when scenario is used:-

```
13:15:54.772 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time: 1540, url: ##url removed###, response: ##Response removed###
13:15:54.795 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - after {
  "featureDir": "C:\\Workspace\\Karate_Demo\\target\\test-classes\\com\\test\\Karate_Demo"
  "scenarioType": "Scenario",
  "featureFileName": "Test.feature",
  "errorMessage": "Test.feature:32 - status code was: 400, expected: 200, response time: 1540, url: ##url removed###, response: ##Response removed###,
  "scenarioDescription": "",
  "scenarioName": "Sample Test"
}
```

How can i get the karate.info to be populated with errorMessage in case of failures when we use Scenario Outline

Comment: Raised issue https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1152

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bug. So please follow this process. Once we can replicate this, we will fix it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Meanwhile see if the `ExecutionHook` gives you better results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475

Comment: Tried with ExecutionHook. I Could see beforeScenario and afterScnenario was executed only once even when feature had Scenario Outline with 10+ rows in the examples. I will submit an issue with details and sample project.

Comment: @jerryV and fixed. please do build locally and test so that we can release sooner