# how to skip karate tests if url is empty

Tags: karate

I want  to skip karate test execution when url is empty.
Currently, during the Jenkins execution if karate.env is not passed, I am not setting url/domainName in karate-config.js. In that case, my karate test cases fails due to blank url/hostName.
I want to skip all karate test execution if value is not being passed in karate.env system property.
Please suggest how can I achieve the above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. You can try hooks, but the API can change in future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475

Comment: I tried * eval if (karate.env == 'NoUrl') karate.abort() in the 'Background' , but still get org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException since its trying to use the url variable I am trying to fetch in next line.

Comment: so please contribute code. this is an open source project