# Is there a way to generate an individual log file for each scenario in karate?

Tags: logging, karate

Currently we are running scenarios in parallel and getting a single karate.log file. Is there a way to generate separate log file for each scenario?

Comment: using roleSiftingAppender in logback-test xml and MDC.Put(discriminator, value) in before scenario worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

No. You might be able to use a [`RuntimeHook`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475) to do this, but it is not officially supported.