# Is it possible to write gherkin each step in logs in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have just started Karate and was wondering if we can write karate gherkin steps in execution logs.

Currently I can write each scenario using below line in background -

- karate.log('Scenario Executing:', karate.scenario.name)

My requirement is to write complete gherkin test case step by step in logs

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported directly. You may be able to write this yourself by using the `ExecutionHook`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475