# How to log debug Id (UUID/uniqueId) in karate report?

Tags: java, debugging, cucumber, karate

How can we log a debug info (like debug id / UUID String / Random Unique Str) for each scenario to the karate report.

It will be useful in Http service/API layer and karate report to track each scenario / service transaction.

i.e., doc string karate / cucumber html report

```
Other Info: XXXX
Unique Debug Id: 175ee69c-ddc1-11ed-b5ea-0242ac120002
```

And this will be passed to API `175ee69c-ddc1-11ed-b5ea-0242ac120002` as well (via header/request body).

And we're trying to log the debug id by using the some JS/Java util with background section and publishing the same in reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically teams add a unique header to each HTTP call by an approach similar to this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#http-header-manipulation

Else look at the RuntimeHook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475