# Custom detailed log in Karate

Tags: spring-boot, logging, karate, feature-file

I want all my karate logs to have the featureName, scenarioName , LineNumeber along the logged message. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has ever asked for this because all of this will be in the HTML report.

If you really want this, my suggestion is use the [`RuntimeHook`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475) and write your own logging implementation or something like that.