# Using undocumented hook possible within runs?

Tags: karate

I see that there is a afterstep function within the hooks code, but when I try to utilize it within karate.configure, I get an error.

```
* karate.configure('afterStep', function(){ karate.call('classpath:adapters/splunklink-updated.feature'); })
js failed:
>>>>
01: karate.configure('afterStep', function(){ karate.call('classpath:adapters/splunklink-updated.feature'); })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: unexpected 'configure' key: 'afterStep'
- com.intuit.karate.core.Config.configure(Config.java:334)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.configure(ScenarioEngine.java:348)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge.configure(ScenarioBridge.java:300)
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

Other hooks we would like to use as well

```
    default void beforeSuite(Suite suite) {

    }

    default void afterSuite(Suite suite) {
        
    }

    default boolean beforeStep(Step step, ScenarioRuntime sr) {
        return true;
    }

    default void afterStep(StepResult result, ScenarioRuntime sr) {
        
    }

    default void beforeHttpCall(HttpRequest request, ScenarioRuntime sr) {
        
    }
    
    default void afterHttpCall(HttpRequest request, Response response, ScenarioRuntime sr) {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no `afterStep` that you can `configure`. You probably have this confused with [`RuntimeHook`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080128/143475).

Comment: That may work, but implementation is unclear from the documentation.  Can a feature or script be executed as a part of the RunTimeHook?  How would the hook be implemented within a Runner or set in a config to execute globably?

Comment: idealy, we would like to ve able to add all the splunk link to all http request "afterHttpCall" if detail could be provided on that approach.